# How does the time() function in C work?

Tags: c, time

Does anyboy have an idea how the `time()` function works?

I was looking online for implementations out of pure curiosity, but could only find the NetBSD implementation of [`difftime()`](https://nxr.netbsd.org/xref/src/lib/libc/time/difftime.c)

Also is there anything that describes the process of calculating the time (non system specific or system specific)?

> Note: I am not looking for answers on how to use `time()` but how it actually works behind the scenes when I call it.

Comment: Then browse for exact implementation of the time() call. Search for standard libraries, ie: [glibc time()](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/unix/time.c) calls [gettimeofday](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/gettimeofday.c) which invokes function __vdso_gettimeofday, which is a VDSO call, but usually it's just `syscall(__NR_gettimeofday, ..)`. Then it goes into linux kernel, probably to `do_gettimeofday()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhere deep down in your computer, typically in hardware, there's a clock oscillator running at some frequency *f*.  For the purposes of this example let's say that it's operating at 1 kHz, or 1,000 cycles per second.  Things are set up so that every cycle of the oscillator triggers a CPU interrupt.

There's also a low-level counter `c`.  Every time the clock interrupt is triggered, the OS increments the counter.  For the moment we'll imagine it increments it by 1, although this won't usually be the case in practice.

The OS also checks the value of the counter as it's incremented.  When `c` equals 1,000, this means that exactly one second has gone by.  At this point the OS does two things:

1. It increments another counter variable, the one that's keeping track of the actual time of day in seconds.  We'll call this other counter `t`.  (It's going to be a big number, so it'll be at least a 32-bit variable, or these days, 64 bits if possible.)
2. It resets `c` to 0.

Finally, when you call `time()`, the kernel simply returns you the current value of `t`.  It's pretty simple, really!

Well, actually, it's somewhat more complicated than that.  I've overlooked the details of how the value of the counter `t` gets set up initially, and how the OS makes sure that the oscillator is running at the right frequency, and a few other things.

When the OS boots, and if it's on a PC or workstation or mainframe or other "big" computer, it's typically got a battery-backed real-time clock it can use to set the initial value of `t` from.  (If the CPU we're talking about is an embedded microcontroller, on the other hand, it may not have any kind of clock, and all of this is moot, and `time()` is not implemented at all.)

Also, when you (as root) call `settimeofday`, you're basically just supplying a value to jam into the kernel's `t` counter.

Also, of course, on a networked system, something like NTP is busy keeping the system's time up-to-date.

NTP can do that in two ways:

1. If it notices that `t` is way off, it can just set it to a new value, more or less as `settimeofday()` does.
2. If it notices that `t` is just a little bit off, or if it notices that the underlying oscillator isn't counting at quite the right frequency, it can try to adjust that frequency.

Adjusting the frequency sounds straightforward enough, but the details can get pretty complicated.  You can imagine that the frequency *f* of the underlying oscillator is adjusted slightly.  Or, you can imagine that *f* is left the same, but when the time interrupt fires, the numeric increment that's added to `c` is adjusted slightly.

In particular, it won't usually be the case that the kernel adds 1 to `c` on each timer interrupt, and that when `c` reaches 1,000, that's the indication that one second has gone by. It's more likely that the kernel will add a number like 1,000,000 to `c` on each timer interrupt, meaning that it will wait until `c` has reached 1,000,000,000 before deciding that one second has gone by. That way, the kernel can make more fine-grained adjustments to the clock rate: if things are running just a little slow, it can change its mind, and add 1,000,001 to `c` on each timer interrupt, and this will make things run just a *tiny* bit faster.  (Something like one part per million, as you can pretty easily see.)

One more thing I overlooked is that `time()` isn't the only way of asking what the system time is.  You can also make calls like `gettimeofday()`, which gives you a sub-second time stamp represented as seconds+microseconds (`struct timeval`), or `clock_gettime()`, which gives you a sub-second time stamp represented as seconds+nanoseconds (`struct timespec`). How are those implemented? Well, instead of just reading out the value of `t`, the kernel can also peek at `c` to see how far into the next second it is. In particular, if `c` is counting up to 1,000,000,000, then the kernel can give you microseconds by dividing `c` by 1,000, and it can give you nanoseconds by returning `c` directly.

---

Two footnotes:

(1) If we've adjusted the frequency, and we're adding 1,000,001 to `c` on each low-level timer tick, `c` will usually not hit 1,000,000,000 exactly, so the test when deciding whether to increment `t` will have to involve a greater-than-or-equal-to condition, and we'll have to subtract 1,000,000,000 from `c`, not just clear it.  In other words, the code will look something like

```
if(c >= 1000000000) {
    t++;
    c -= 1000000000;
}
```

(2) Since `time()` and `gettimeofday()` are two of the simplest system calls around, and since programs calling them may (by definition) be particularly sensitive to any latency due to system call overhead, these are the calls that are most likely to be implemented based on the [vDSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSO) mechanism, if it's in use.

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I was looking for! After you understand the concept on the low level, the implementation in the kernel doesn't seem that complicated at all.

Do you know any kind of ressources on topics related to this?

Comment: @Nils I do not know of any resources.  I wish there were some.  I've worked this out by examining the Linux kernel source.  I hope to write up some sort of comprehensive documentation some day.

Comment: Seeing a documentation about this would make things alot easier. But reading the kernel source is where I am at then for the time beeing. (I checked your website, you don't seem to have a place where I can get updates from you other than checking your homepage, right?) - Thanks again for the elaborate answer!

Comment: Does it take a context switch to get the time, or does the OS usually have a simpler way of returning it?

Comment: @TodorMarkov There is indeed a simpler way, avoiding a context switch, at least under some Linux kernels: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSO.  I know of only a few syscalls which are ever implemented using vDSO, but fetching the time is definitely at the top of the list.

Answer (score 1):

The C specification does not say anything about *how* library functions work. It only states the observable behavior. The internal workings is both compiler and platform dependent.

> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
>     #include <time.h>
>     time_t time(time_t *timer);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The time function determines the current calendar time. The encoding of the value is unspecified.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The time function returns the implementation's best approximation to the current calendar time. The value (time_t)(-1) is returned if the calendar time is not available. If timer is not a null pointer, the return value is also assigned to the object it points to.

https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html

Here is one implementation:

```
time_t
time (timer)
     time_t *timer;
{
  __set_errno (ENOSYS);

  if (timer != NULL)
    *timer = (time_t) -1;
  return (time_t) -1;
}
```

https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/time/time.c

Comment: Example implementation code is a bit pointless, as it seems to describe system where timer is not available.

Answer (score 0):

there are time is funcation a uesd application to run a work.
then work is define a theroy to uesd a line a layer in define application are  value
this is called a work and time managment a soure are accept in variable and work/time solulation in work method in soures.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).